# The order of arrangement of windows in QT

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qwidget

Sorry for my English. I need to implement the order of the `QWidget`. I have a stack of objects `QWidget`.
And I need to place the window in the order they appear in a stack.

For example:

Stack: `window1 -> window2 -> window3`

From this example `window2` always closes `window3`, but it, in turn, closes `window1`

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Window> window_ptr;
std::stack<window_ptr> m_windowsStack;
```

Class window:

```
class Window
{
public:
    ...
private:
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<QWidget> m_window;
};
```

As it can be implemented with the help of `QWidget`. Maybe the `QWidget` has a feature that is responsible for the priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) to switch between windows? I believe it provides a means to swap between your windows.